# Object Detection in Fisheye Images

Tags: computer-vision

I have a camera that uses a fish-eye lens and need to run an object detection network like YOLO or SSD with it.

Should I rectify/un-distort the incoming image first? Is that computationally expensive?

Or, should I try to train the network using fish-eye images?

Many thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use a model that was pretrained on perspective rectilinear images, you will probably get poor results either way. On one hand, objects in raw fisheye images have a different appearance from the same objects in perspective images and many will be misdetected. On the other hand, you can't really "undistort" a fisheye image with a large field of view, and when you try - it looks very different from real perspective pictures. Some researchers are doing neither and investigating other alternatives instead.

If you have a training set of fisheye images, you can train a model on the raw fisheye images. It is a more difficult task for the network to learn, because the same object changes appearance when it moves, while convolutional neural networks are shift invariant, but nevertheless it is possible and has been demonstrated in the literature.